# How to access internal nodes of a JSON with Dumbledroid?

Tags: java, android, json, httprequest

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "status": 200,
        "msg": "OK"
    },
    "response": {
        "blog": {
            "title": "Poema do Dia",
            "name": "poemadodia",
            "posts": 381,
            "url": "http://poemadodia.tumblr.com/",
            "updated": 1380565297,
            "description": "Um pouco do que eu penso e sinto em forma de rimas e prosas.",
            "ask": true,
            "ask_anon": true,
            "is_nsfw": false,
            "share_likes": false
        },
        "posts": [
            {
                "blog_name": "poemadodia",
                "id": 62732663432,
                "post_url": "http://poemadodia.tumblr.com/post/62732663432/maluquinha",
                "slug": "maluquinha",
                "type": "text",
                "date": "2013-09-30 18:21:37 GMT",
                "timestamp": 1380565297,
                "state": "published",
                "format": "html",
                "reblog_key": "gdXogVQ1",
                "tags": [
                    "amor",
                    "soneto"
                ],
                "short_url": "http://tmblr.co/ZnrkhxwRA7g8",
                "highlighted": [],
                "note_count": 1,
                "title": "Maluquinha",
                "body": "<p>Ela é doida, demais<br/>Acorda daquele jeito<br/>Mas ela me satisfaz<br/>Dorme sobre meu peito</p>\n<p>Um amor que não esperei<br/>Que não foi de propósito<br/>Se tornou o que sonhei<br/>Mesmo sendo meu opósito</p>\n<p>Hoje a amo simplesmente<br/>E não me sinto tão carente<br/>Ela é a minha medida</p>\n<p>Começou inconsciente<br/>Um amor tão displicente<br/>Mas o amor da minha vida</p>"
            }
        ],
        "total_posts": 375
    }
}
```

And these classes to abstract these data:

**PoemaDoDia.java**:

```
package br.com.wgbn.vo;

import io.leocad.dumbledroid.data.AbstractModel;
import io.leocad.dumbledroid.data.DataType;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.content.Context;

public class PoemaDoDia extends AbstractModel {

    public List<Meta> meta;
    public List<Response> response;

    public PoemaDoDia() {
        super("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/poemadodia.tumblr.com/posts/text");
    }

    /* 
     * api_key=xxx
     * limit=1 
     * offset=374 
     * */
    public void load(Context ctx, String offset) throws Exception {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new Vector<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", "xxx"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit", "1"));
        if (Integer.parseInt(offset) > 0){
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("offset", offset));
        }


        super.load(ctx, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected DataType getDataType() {
        return DataType.JSON;
    }

}
```

**Meta.java**:

```
package br.com.wgbn.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Meta implements Serializable {

    public int status;
    public String msg;

}
```

**Response.java**:

```
package br.com.wgbn.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Response implements Serializable {

    public List<Blog> blog;
    public List<Posts> posts;
    public int total_posts;

}
```

**Blog.java**:

```
package br.com.wgbn.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Blog implements Serializable {

    public String title;
    public String name;
    public int posts;
    public String url;
    public String updated;
    public String description;
    public Boolean ask;
    public Boolean ask_anon;
    public Boolean is_nsfw;
    public Boolean share_likes;

}
```

**Posts.java**:

```
package br.com.wgbn.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Posts implements Serializable {

    public String blog_name;
    public String id;
    public String post_url;
    public String slug;
    public String type;
    public String date;
    public String timestamp;
    public String state;
    public String format;
    public String reblog_key;
    public List<String> tags;
    public String short_url;
    public List<String> highlighted;
    public int note_count;
    public String title;
    public String body;

}
```

Implemented the Dumbledroid for the work to be more practical, but I can not access the returned nodes.
https://github.com/leocadiotine/Dumbledroid

The error appears to me is this:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"posts":[{"tags":["amor","soneto"],"body":"<p>Ela é doida, demais<br\/>Acorda daquele jeito<br\/>Mas ela me satisfaz<br\/>Dorme sobre meu peito<\/p>\n<p>Um amor que não esperei<br\/>Que não foi de propósito<br\/>Se tornou o que sonhei<br\/>Mesmo sendo meu opósito<\/p>\n<p>Hoje a amo simplesmente<br\/>E não me sinto tão carente<br\/>Ela é a minha medida<\/p>\n<p>Começou inconsciente<br\/>Um amor tão displicente<br\/>Mas o amor da minha vida<\/p>","blog_name":"poemadodia","post_url":"http:\/\/poemadodia.tumblr.com\/post\/62732663432\/maluquinha","reblog_key":"gdXogVQ1","state":"published","highlighted":[],"format":"html","date":"2013-09-30 18:21:37 GMT","type":"text","timestamp":1380565297,"id":62732663432,"title":"Maluquinha","short_url":"http:\/\/tmblr.co\/ZnrkhxwRA7g8","slug":"maluquinha","note_count":1}],"blog":{"share_likes":false,"title":"Poema do Dia","is_nsfw":false,"updated":1380565297,"description":"Um pouco do que eu penso e sinto em forma de rimas e prosas.","name":"poemadodia","posts":381,"ask":true,"ask_anon":true,"url":"http:\/\/poemadodia.tumblr.com\/"},"total_posts":375} at response of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I've been researching and error must be because the JSON received contains an Object and not an Array, but as the JSON is generated by the Tumblr API, I have no control over it, and do not go out and solve this my problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i think your parsing JSONObject as JSONArray.. can you post your parsing codes..

Comment: The problem is that I'm not manipulating anything. I only wrote the classes of abstraction. All work import and processing of JSON is the responsibility of the library Dumbledroid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem on your code is because you're declaring some elements as `List`s, but they are single objects. For example, on `PoemaDoDia.java`, you have:

```
public List<Meta> meta;
```

and the correspondent JSON is not an array:

```
"meta": {
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "OK"
}
```

So, if you correct these issues, Dumbledroid will work. Just change `PoemaDoDia.java`'s attributes to:

```
public Meta meta;
public Response response;
```

and `Response.java`'s attributes to:

```
public Blog blog;
public List<Posts> posts;
public int total_posts;
```

and it will work.

Hope it helps!

P.S.: it's good to remove your Tumblr API key from your question. People could use it for bad purposes, and your key can be blocked!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @leocadiotine! I really liked your pretndo library and use it whenever you have to read a JSON or XML. Thanks!

Comment: @WalterBarreiroNeto Cool! Anytime you have a question, just drop me a line here!